# What is the difference to declare a pointer before the malloc

Tags: c, malloc

I am learning about malloc function & I see this difference but I cannot understand it

What is the difference between

```
ptr = (*int) malloc(sizeof(int)*N)
```

and

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*N)
```

Comment: `ptr = (*int) malloc(sizeof(int)*N)` is invalid syntax (specifically `*int` part is) and emit compile error while `ptr= malloc(sizeof(int)*N)` doesn't.

Comment: Casting the return of `malloc` has been discussed [once or twice before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: changing the tags makes answer almost off topic

Answer (score 1):

In `C` cast of the `malloc` is considered the bad practice.

`C++` is more type strict and you need to cast if you want to assign pointer with pointer of other type. But I would rather avoid direct use of the `malloc` (and generally pointers) in the C++ program.

In both I would rather use object in the `sizeof` operator

`ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr)*N);`

Comment: UV: cast-less `malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * ...` idiom.